# Apps Script Executions User Record

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to know which users in my organisation are executing a script.  I can see on the project page that there's two users, however how can I see who those users are?

I am the owner of the project.

Comment: Add a log in your script and in the log print logged in user's email

Comment: That only works when I execute it within the scripts editing section.  When the user runs it logs nothing.  Also doesn't the log only show the last execution?

Comment: Enable StackDriver logging and use `console.log` to log user emails.

Comment: No console.log will work for every user and it will log everything.

Comment: My solution is to have a second `logs` spreadsheet defined that is written to any time a script is run. I don't log the user's email address, but you can certainly do that with `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()`.

Comment: You can't track them without their permission. They need to explicitly authorize the script

Comment: Granted, they will likely accept whatever permissions are requested. "Oh, this needs to modify spreadsheets in my Drive? Ok. External requests? Why not!"

Comment: How is the script being triggered? Are you using simple/installable triggers, a custom menu, a button, a web app ?

Comment: console.log doesn't work for server side scripts, or logging to me.

I can log to a sheet, which is in my drive, so it may ask for new permissions, however this is a corporate app, so it's fine, they will accept.

The user goes to a script web app and then clicks a button which sets up a time based triggers.  I want to know WHO has triggers set up and running, however I can't see that.  I now got it to email me once a day with a list of users as part of the script, however I thought the script creator should be able to see this under executions in the scripts.google.com interface